# Can I use a file with MySQL transactions to update a mariadb?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sh

I need to **update a column** or **add a row** to a database named, "**CENIC**" and a table named, '**CCC_Master_Circuit_Table**'.  The parms and data to update are saved in a text file in the format shown in Example1 and Example2.

The Example1 file is updated daily and will have changed data on the right side of the '=' sign.

- The primary and lookup Key is named, "**CCC Key ID** ".
- If the CCC Key ID is a new key, a new row with CCC Key ID needs to be added, and then the columns updated with the values in the text file (see Example1 below for format).
- If data is Null, it needs to be ignored and not overwrite the col in the table.

**Example 1: "Yesterday's Run" where Columns written to the Table were:**

CCC Key ID = CCC-2477

**CCC Project Status = PROD-16.2: (2016) or prior**

CCC Site Attributes = Cricket_Usage

**BLDING  = College**

IMPACT  =  Low

Resulting In the CENIC.CCC_Master_Circuit_Table, Row:Col Update below:

---

CCC Key ID|CCC Project Status|CCC Site Attributes|BLDING |IMPACT|

---

CCC-2477  |(2016) or prior   |Cricket_Usage      |College|Low   |

---

**Example2 Today's Run where data has changed in today's text file for the columns **CCC Project Status:** and **BLDING  =  01 CENTER**.

CCC Key ID = CCC-2477

**CCC Project Status = Null**

CCC Site Attributes = Cricket_Usage - 01 Yes

**BLDING  =  01 CENTER**

IMPACT  =  04 Low

- The update should be applied to the CENIC.CCC_Master_Circuit_Table's **BLDING** column because there is changed data value named, **CENTER**.
- However, the **CCC Project Status = Null** should be ignored and not updated in the table".

And so, **After the SQL Update, the Table's column values should be:**

---

CCC Key ID|CCC Project Status|CCC Site Attributes|BLDING |IMPACT|

---

CCC-2477|**(2016) or prior**   |Cricket_Usage      |**CENTER**|Low   |

---

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an arbitrarily formatted text document to update databases.

With a small bit of script writing you can create an [UPDATE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/update/) SQL statement stored in `$SQL` and execute it with:

```
 echo $SQL | mysql {databasename}
```